# What is the default valu for double?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change data-type double(10,2) to double(20,3) in cpanel/phpmyadmin but it will updating only double,
In Mysql what is the default value of datatype double if not passing parameter like double(10,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test, it allows you up to 15 digit then after that it will display 2.5e15 (2500000000000000).

Answer (score 0):

DOUBLE[(M,D)] [ZEROFILL] holds double-precision numeric values, pretty similar to FLOAT double-precision, except for its allowable range, which is -1.7976931348623157E+308 to -2.2250738585072014E-308, 0, and 2.2250738585072014E-308 to 1.7976931348623157E+308

Answer (score 0):

You can define the display length (M) and the number of decimals (D). 
This is not required and will default to 16,4, where 4 is the number of decimals.